# Understanding non-strictness in Haskell with a recursive example

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, strictness

What is the difference between this two, in terms of evaluation?

Why this "obeys" (how to say?) non-strictness

```hs
recFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
recFilter _ [] = []
recFilter p (h:tl) = if (p h) 
  then h : recFilter p tl
  else recFilter p tl
```

while this doesn't?

```hs
recFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int -> [a]
recFilter _ xs 0 = xs
recFilter p (h:tl) len
  | p(h)  = recFilter p (tl ++ [h]) (len-1)
  | otherwise = recFilter p tl (len-1)
```

Is it possible to write a tail-recursive function non-strictly?

To be honest I also don't understand the call stack of the first example, because I can't see where that `h:` goes. Is there a way to see this in ghci?

Comment: Uhm, doesn't the second snippet lack a base case? The function always recurses, even when `len` becomes zero or negative.

Comment: It returns `h : recFilter p tl`, so the `recFilter p tl` part will *not* be evaluated unless it is needed by the result. This on the other hand with your second recursive function that will keep making recursive calls, and does not even eventually returns an object. If it had returned the accumulator in case the end of the list is reached, then it would thus have to evaluate until that point.

Comment: @chi: it is actually even worse, it manipulates the accumulator by adding an item to that list, and thus even if there is a base case, if there is one item for which the predicate matches, it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @chi you're right, I added a correction. It was present in the original code listing.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I noticed that, but I guess we want to recurse on `len`, not on the list. Indeed the OP just did that.

Comment: A terminology note: the first `recFilter` is not non-strict. (Eliminating the double-negative: the first `recFilter` is strict.) However, it does satisfy the definition of being *productive*, and also the definition of being *guarded recursion* (one way to guarantee productivity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second implementation does not make much sense: a variable named `len` will *not* contain the length of the list. You thus need to pass this, for infinite lists, this would not work, since there is no length at all.

You likely want to produce something like:

```
recFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
recFilter p = go []
    where go ys [] = ys  -- (1)
          go ys (x:xs) | p x = go (ys ++ [x]) xs
                       | otherwise = go ys xs
```

where we thus have an accumulator to which we append the items in the list, and then eventually return the accumulator.

The problem with the second approach is that as long as the accumulator is not returned, Haskell will need to keep recursing until at least we reach [*weak head normal form (WHNF)*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form). This means that if we pattern match the result with `[]` or `(_:_)`, we will need at least have to recurse until case one, since the other cases only produce a new expression, and it will thus not yield a data constructor on which we can pattern match.

This in contrast to the first filter where if we pattern match on `[]` or `(_:_)` it is sufficient to stop at the first case (1), or the third case 93) where the expression produces an object with a list data constructor. Only if we require extra elements to pattern match, for example `(_:_:_)`, it will require to evaluate the `recFilter p tl` in case (2) of the first implementation:

```
recFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
recFilter _ [] = []  -- (1)
recFilter p (h:tl) = if (p h) 
  then h : recFilter p tl  -- (2)
  else recFilter p tl
```

For more information, see the [*Laziness* section of the Wikibook on Haskell](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness) that describes how laziness works with *thunks*.

Answer (score 4):

The non-tail recursive function roughly consumes a portion of the input (the first element) to produce a portion of the output (well, if it's not filtered out at least). Then recursion handles the next portion of the input, and so on.

Your tail recursive function will recurse until `len` becomes zero, and only at that point it will output the whole result.

Consider this pseudocode:

```
def rec1(p,xs):
   case xs:
      []     -> []
      (y:ys) -> if p(y): print y
                rec1(p,ys)
```

and compare it with this accumulator-based variant. I'm not using `len` since I use a separate accumulator argument, which I assume to be initially empty.

```
def rec2(p,xs,acc):
   case xs:
      []     -> print acc
      (y:ys) -> if p(y): 
                   rec2(p,ys,acc++[y])
                else:
                   rec2(p,ys,acc)
```

`rec1` prints *before* recursing: it does not need to inspect the whole input list to start printing its output. It works in a "steraming" fashion, in a sense. Instead, `rec2` will only start to print at the very end, after the input list was completely scanned.

In your Haskell code there are no `print`s, of course, but you can thing of returning `x : function call` as "printing `x`", since `x` is made available to the caller of our function *before* `function call` is actually made. (Well, to be pedantic this depends on how the caller will consume the output list, but I'll neglect this.)

Hence the non-tail recursive code can also work on infinite lists. Even on finite inputs, performance is improved: if we call `head (rec1 p xs)`, we only evaluate `xs` until the first non-discarded element. By contrast `head (rec2 p xs)` would fully filter the whole list `xs`, even we don't need that.